# Rename only the local version of SVN directory

Tags: svn, directory, rename

I am trying to figure out a way to rename only the local copy of an svn directory, but leave the server copy with the name that it already has.

My svn server has the following setup (obviously just an example):

```
svnserver.com/1/2/3/4/5
```

I have checked out the directory 3 to my local computer but not any of the directories above it.

```
/localcomputer/3/4/5
```

Only on my local computer, I want to rename directory 3 to something more recognisable, but the version on the svn server must still be called 3.

```
/localcomputer/X/4/5
```

Is there a way that I can achieve this? In the past I have screwed things up when I have tried renaming things so am not overly keen on a trial and error approach. I feel like because I am trying to rename the highest level directory that I have checked out, it might be possible (as opposed to renaming something inside of a checked out directory, which I doubt you could do).

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout a working copy with a directory name of your choosing. See examples in [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html), such as `svn co http://server/repos/trunk my-working-copy`. Equivalently, if you checked out into `my-working-copy` you can rename that directory to `other-working-copy` without any issues. You cannot, however, rename any subdirectories in your working copy without introducing local modifications to your working copy status.

Comment: Thanks. Using Finder, I just renamed the highest directory that I checked out. I tried a commit command and it worked fine so renaming the working directory had no effect on that. All good.